# How to remove duplicate columns

Tags: mysql

I have some tables like this [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a648b/3).

I want this table to select only the following values (remove duplicates):

```
from | to
46  0  
46  18  
46  50  
46  39  
46  11   
46  12  
46  56
```

I use `DISTINCT` keyword, but this returns the following values:

```
46  0  
46  18  
46  50  
46  39  
46  11  
11  46  
46  12  
46  56
```

Comment: Please do not ask your questions more than once, especially on the same day, as it risks causing duplicate effort.

Answer (score 3):

**[Greatest and Least](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)**

```
SELECT distinct greatest(`from`,`to`),least(`from`,`to`)
from `tsk_private_message`
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a648b/5)**

Comment: But then you can't tell what is `from` and what is `to`

Comment: @juergend Thats true!!!

Comment: thank's,very much,:'(

Comment: And for all column with greatest ,least just(`from`,`to`)???

Comment: There is a similar question on StackOverflow covering this which you can adapt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Comment: A very big clue... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a648b/15